# Chat top bar lost its padding

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, top-bar

The padding in the chat top bar (seen in non-room views, e.g. [all rooms here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/)) is off under "My Communities" list, and achievements dialog:

> [image: padding off in my communities list]

and...

> [image: padding off in achievements dialog]

and...

> [image: padding off in inbox dialog]

Affected browsers/OS:

- Chrome latest stable version (65.0.3325.181) under Windows 7 and 10
- (Arch)Linux.
- Firefox

Do also note that the top bar itself is still following the *old* design.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: I guess the team just has to keep playing whack-a-Eggman's-mech with CSS glitches in the top bar...

Comment: @SonicWizard yup, fix in one place, cause a bug in another place. Classic.

Comment: Well... if they'd rolled out the new top bar to chat... ;)

Comment: @Catija race condition indeed (between fixing the bug and deploying new top bar in chat), both in 6-8 weeks. :-D

Comment: Happens on Area 51 too.

Comment: @Glorfindel no repro, looking fine for me in Area 51 main, Area 51 Discussion Zone, and stackexchange.com - only chat (all domains) is infected.

Comment: Could be browser/OS-dependent, then: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZIqz.png (FF, macOS)

Comment: @Glorfindel huh, weird. Well, no doubt something in the CSS is broken, hopefully fixing it will fix all those at once.

Comment: [Repro several days later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309342/162102) (though it was working in between), in Firefox.

Comment: @Monica thanks, added to the report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like balpha fixed this on May 15th. Note that only non-room pages include the relevant css, since only those pages include a top-bar. However, this does mean that folks using [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms) will continue to see a broken layout for topbar dialogs.

---

The dropdowns are now using [stacks.css](https://stackoverflow.design/). Which... Chat doesn't include.

You can include it manually by dropping something like this into your browser console:

```
$("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Shared/stacks.css'>").appendTo(document.head)
```

...but this *will* tend to make the rest of chat look a bit funky due to font overrides.