# Achievements dropdown lost its spacing, only on chat

Tags: bug, design, chat, achievements-dialog

Here's what I currently see on chat.se:

[image: screenshot]

Badge text has lost its indentation, some icons are bottom-aligned instead of top-aligned, and the rep-change number sometimes floats above the text.  SE sites aren't affected; this is what I see on Meta.SE:

[image: screenshot]

I think I saw normal behavior in chat 12-24 hours ago.

A [similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309154/chat-top-bar-lost-its-padding) was reported last week, but it was fixed in the meantime and has now broken again.

Comment: It's because the top bar hasn't been upgraded to the new one yet. They're working on the responsive layout. This broke on Thursday or Friday, too. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309154/284336

Comment: @Catija it hasn't been broken all along, though; something changed recently.  I'm hoping they can identify what.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I didn't duplicate vote.

Comment: The other one doesn't have any answers, so maybe these are *functionally* dupes, but I haven't tested on all the platforms identified there, so I don't know.  We'll see if the community thinks it should be a dupe.  I don't feel strongly; I just want to get a clear report so it can be fixed. :-)

Comment: No answers because the bug isn't fixed yet. Some bugs exist for long long years without ever being fixed (especially minor design bugs), so "no answers" isn't relevant on meta sites. :)