# Alignment issue in Area 51 main site - site switcher, inbox and achievements

Tags: bug, design, area-51

The content in the site switcher, inbox and achievements of the Area 51 are misaligned. I can verify the issue in recent Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers with 100% zoom.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309154/chat-top-bar-lost-its-padding

Comment: @Shog9 I'd say dupe, since root cause is the same, no?

Comment: The root cause is the same, but the problem is subtly different.