# Top bar dialog alignment issues when viewing full site on iOS

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, ios

Probably related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309154/chat-top-bar-lost-its-padding) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309429/alignment-issue-in-area-51-main-site-site-switcher-inbox-and-achievements): when viewing the full site in Safari on iOS, the dropdowns in the top bar have their layouts messed up. For example, in the achievements dialog the rows are too small:

[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>