# Everything is too crowded in dropdown on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, stack-exchange-button

Look at this:

> [image]

There are several problems:

- | help | chat | log out | is on its own line and should be on the same line as Area 51
- Right angle thing (∟) is out of place
- No space between site icon and site name anywhere
- No space between lines in the "Your Communities" list

Please fix.

Comment: Guess this probably a duplicate of [Chat top bar lost its padding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309154/307988) (since A51 doesn't have a proper new top bar)