# Area51 top bar popup contains narrow strings

Tags: bug, design, area-51, top-bar

As you can see on the pictures below Area51 top bar popup contains narrow strings in some cases:

Site switch:

> [image: sites]

Reputation change:

> [image: reps]

Comment: Seems like it's likely a similar problem to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309154/chat-top-bar-lost-its-padding

Comment: @Catija indeed. Whatever fix deployed on the Q&A sites probably can't be deployed on Area 51 due to it having ancient code base. Most likely it won't be fixed. :/

Comment: And now you see why I left that bug un-dup'd, @Shadow...

Comment: @Shog9 indeed. Area 51 is below chat in the "codebase priority list" or whatever it can be called... :-)